# How do I turn off push notifications in my Vivo Y53?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, whatsapp-messenger

Whenever my screen is on, and I am connected to network, my Whatsapp messages come directly in the middle of whatever I am doing, which disconnects me and makes me lose all my work. Any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Open WhatsApp.
2. Tap on three dots on top-right corner of WhatsApp and Select Settings.
3. Goto Notifications.

   Under Message Notifications, there is an option called `popup notification`. It have several sub options which is easy to identify by its name itself.

   - No popup: never pop-up on any screen
   - Only when screen on
   - Only when screen off
   - Always show popup.
     Also set the same for Group notifications.

**Note** : If you wish reset to default, tap on three dots on top-right corner while inside Notifications page, which have option to reset notification settings.